# Can a jsp file hold javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hello everyone quick question.

First time working with java script
I have a jsp file that will create a data grid and one of the columns of the data grid are checkboxes. My question is can a JSP file contain javascript in it or will I have to create a different file for just the javascript. The function of the java script will be a select all button.

If JSP can hold javascript where does the code belong? by this I mean what headers does the code reside int?

```
<html>
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059168/java-websocket-client-in-jsp-possible/25059382#25059382

The generic answer is: JSP can contain anything that a regular HTML page can contain. JSP is an HTML extended with JSP tags that are processed on a server. After the JSP tags are processed and a response is generated there is no any difference between that response and a regular HTML.

So, the question really is where to store the java scripts in an HTML. I think, the cleanest way would be to put them to a separate file or files and then use a `<script>` tag with an 'src' attribute:

```
<script src="<java-script-url>"></script>
```

But in cases when java scripts are not that big and complicated, it's OK to include them to the page itself under `<head>` element of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Script tags should be added under the head tag of the HTML node.
The script tag can then simply contain JavaScript.

This should not be any different from adding a script tag to a normal html page.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --><jsp:text> </jsp:text></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Add inline javascript to the body of the jsp:text (jsp:text may not be necessary, I am not sure), or add a src="" attribute containing the path relative (or absolute) to the URL the browser will consume the page from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it technically can. You'd simply put it under a `<script>` tag inside `<head>`. However, I recommend including a JavaScript file using a `<script>` tag, instead of inserting JavaScript directly into your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dependency between JavaScript and JSP because JavaScript is used for client side scripting and JSP is used to produce HTML pages or contents dynamically using Java EE. JavaScript can be used along with HTML on any browser that supports JavaScript (all browsers we use for work and development supports JavaScript).

Feel free to write JavaScript functions and code for HTML page to create an interactive website, it doesn't matter whether you are using ASP, JSP or PHP for server side scripting and dynamic HTML content generation because all these frameworks produce and use HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Media Contents. Your browser can only understand HTML, CSS and JavaScript, its the web server application which understands JSP and its Java code.

Why don't you write this code in your JSP page and check yourself whether it works or not.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello World!');</script>
```

JavaScript is not limited to be written inside `<head>` tag, you can write it anywhere you want in a HTML page. There are some cases in which you would like to write a JavaScript function at the end of `<body>` tag.